# Can we have genric Properties?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can we have a Generic properties?I have a requirement of storing the data.So i have taken class with Generic Properties.When i add the data to that Property am getting an error that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" .please suggest me some idea.

```
class GeneralClass
    {
        private List<int> _student_rollnumber;
        public List<string> _student_name;
        public List<int> Student_RollNumber
        {
            get { return _student_rollnumber; }
            set { _student_rollnumber = value; }
        }
        public List<string> Student_Name
        {
            get { return _student_name; }
            set { _student_name = value; }
        }
    }
```

i have used the Class in Button Click.

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              GeneralClass obj = new GeneralClass();
              obj.Student_RollNumber.Add(int.Parse(txtbx_rollnum.Text));
              obj.Student_Name.Add(txtbx_SName.Text);
              MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message from form");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing to do with generics.

You simply didn’t initialize your member variables, i.e. `_student_rollnumber` and `_student_name`, so they’re `null` when you try to `Add` values to them.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising the lists, so they default to `null`, which means that you get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to add to them in your click-handler method.

```
class GeneralClass
{
    // initialise to a new List<int>, otherwise it will default to null
    private List<int> _student_rollnumber = new List<int>();

    // initialise to a new List<string>, otherwise it will default to null
    private List<string> _student_name = new List<string>();

    public List<int> Student_RollNumber
    {
        get { return _student_rollnumber; }
        // chances are that you don't need the setter, uncomment it if you do
        //set { _student_rollnumber = value; }
    }

    public List<string> Student_Name
    {
        get { return _student_name; }
        // chances are that you don't need the setter, uncomment it if you do
        //set { _student_name = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class GeneralClass
    {
        public GeneralClass
        {
           _student_rollnumber = new List<int>();
           _student_name = new List<string>();
        }

        private List<int> _student_rollnumber;
        public List<string> _student_name;
        public List<int> Student_RollNumber
        {
            get { return _student_rollnumber; }
            set { _student_rollnumber = value; }
        }
        public List<string> Student_Name
        {
            get { return _student_name; }
            set { _student_name = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Great man!. This is really very helpful link to understand generic properties.